# Automatically sort ko.observableArray as bound properties change

Tags: knockout.js

is there a way to automatically sort an observable array when a bound property is changed? I believe in the following example, my view is updated when i add a new person, but can I get the view to refresh and apply my sorting function if one of the person's age is changed?

```
person = {
   age: ko.observable();
}

viewModel = {

   people: ko.observableArray([]),

   someSortFunction: function() {
       this.people.sort(function(person1, person2) {
           return person2.age() - person1.age();
       });
    }
}

<div data-bind="foreach: people">
   <span data-bind="text: age"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe an observable and act whenever that observable changes:

```
person.age.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    viewModel.someSortFunction();
});
```

Comment: Note: there are issues with this approach that those considering it will want to be aware of. First: in order to ensure that the observable array continually sorts you will have to manually subscribe to the same property on every element in the array. Second: the subscriptions remain unless you manually remove them on every element as you remove it from the observable array. This creates the potential for a memory leak. Use this technique with great care.

Comment: @Randolpho :: quite true...what may seem obvious may lead to an error similar to 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' in which the 'subscribe' continues to be run per sort...and never stops